# Software SPI Implementation

Tags: c, stm32, spi

I'm thinking about creating my own pure-C software SPI library because there are none available (as far as I can tell).

Which also worries me - why *aren't* there any software SPI libraries? Is there some hardware limitation I'm not considering?

EDIT:

I've decided to write my own library due to how buggy the SPI peripheral is in STM32. [Especially](https://my.st.com/public/STe2ecommunities/mcu/Lists/cortex_mx_stm32/Flat.aspx?RootFolder=https%3a%2f%2fmy.st.com%2fpublic%2fSTe2ecommunities%2fmcu%2fLists%2fcortex_mx_stm32%2fSPI%20Software%20Chip%20Select&FolderCTID=0x01200200770978C69A1141439FE559EB459D7580009C4E14902C3CDE46A77F0FFD06506F5B&currentviews=79) in [8 bit mode](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/153657/stm32-spi-peripheral-bug), but I've also had a [lot of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28588374/spi-fails-to-read-first-6-bytes) with 16 bit mode. Many other issues I didn't even bother documenting.

I've now written the software implementation (it is pretty easy) and in works just fine.

Comment: There probably *are* software SPI libraries.

Comment: I'd imagine few people would ever need one given that all STM32 devices have a rich selection of _hardware_ SPI peripherals with each one being pin remappable, has DMA and interrupt support and can operate with a throughput of HCLK/2.

Comment: @AndyBrown Added my reasoning for writing my own software implementation.

Comment: Considering SPI is such a common peripheral, you would think that STM would get it correct, there are indeed issues with it - specifically with the Hardware/Software slaveselecting and their ambiguous documentation around it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why aren't there any software SPI libraries?

Because it's about 10 lines of code each for the WriteByte and ReadByte functions, and most of that is bit banging processor-specific registers. The higher level protocol depends on the device connected to the SPI. Here's [what wikipedia has to say](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface_Bus#Standards) on the subject

> The SPI bus is a de facto standard. However, the lack of a formal
>   standard is reflected in a wide variety of protocol options. Different
>   word sizes are common. Every device defines its own protocol,
>   including whether or not it supports commands at all. Some devices are
>   transmit-only; others are receive-only. Chip selects are sometimes
>   active-high rather than active-low. Some protocols send the least
>   significant bit first.

So there's really no point in making a library. You just write the code for each specific situation, and combination of devices.

Answer (score 1):

Although the others have answered that `its just bitbanging`; I would argue that there is benefit to writing a *small* layer:

- If you don't use a HAL, or the Standard Libs (like myself) you can write a layer to deal with initialization which can do things as per the initialisation sequence of the chip.
- You can map all your interrupt vectors for a specific peripheral in this layer utilising callback mechanisms
- Create separation between application and system domains which is a core principle for modular design
- Increase of code reusability utilising techniques such as function pointers and common interfaces
- Add input validation on settings/parameters that would otherwise cause code duplication if no layer was used. For example, ensuring that the HCLK does not exceed 180MHz on the stm32f429 when initialising it.

Whilst it is true that to send data generally all you need to do is set a register, but more often that not the initialisation sequence is complicated.

With the increase in power and capacity in microcontrollers along with project size, its important to implement balanced design choices that promote scalability and maintainability - especially in commercial projects.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for microcontrollers then you can have your own SPI library.
You need to use bit-banging technique for that.
There are software SPI libraries available.
As every microcontroller have different PORT architecture and registers those are not generic and they are specific for that controller only.

e.g. For 8051 architecture you can find [this](http://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/3524).